# Return one of two (or more) lambdas in C++

Tags: c++, lambda

Since C++ lambdas have unique unnamed types, something like this doesn't work:

```
auto select_lambda() {
    if (someCondition())
        return []() { return 1; };
    else
        return []() { return 2; };
}
```

They can be wrapped into an `std::function`:

```
std::function<int()> select_lambda() { /* same body */ }
```

But this has a significant overhead. Is there a better way to achieve something similar? I had some preliminary ideas but none which I got working yet.

Comment: What overhead are you worried about? If you're close enough to metal that you're worried about the overhead of `std::function`, you shouldn't be using lambdas in the first place.

Comment: "_But this has a significant overhead_" - What is that?

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the lambdas? For instance, will they be stateless as in here? If not, you'll essentially end up with `std::function` or something very close to it.

Comment: Do the lambdas have closures? If not, you could convert return them as function pointers.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo lambdas are just a nice syntax for objects with `operator()`, they get readily inlined and optimized out.

Comment: "Significant overhead?" *Benchmark needed* to prove this.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR Unfortunately they won't. I'll have to see if my ideas work out then or remain with `std::function`.

Comment: Are your lambdas stateless? Can you use function pointers?

Comment: This may not necessarily help, but if you can make your condition be static, then you can use `if constexpr` so that `auto` deduces the specific lambda per branch. This will probably lead to the best inlining opportunities since there won't be any functional type-erasure. Of course, profile and benchmark first to be sure.

Comment: how much overhead exactly are you measuring?

Answer (score 10):

If your lambdas don't need to capture anything then you can prepend `+` to each of them to convert them to a regular function pointer:

```
auto select_lambda() {
    if (someCondition())
        return +[]() { return 1; };
    else
        return +[]() { return 2; };
}
```

If you need capturing lambdas then `std::function` would seem to be the best way to go.

Comment: Well.... _one of_ the games in town, if you want to be pedantic. C++ does have [`std::packaged_task`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task), though its general intended use is much narrower.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't trying to get you to edit your answer -- I was just being pedantic since there technically is at least one other solution

Comment: @Human-Compiler No worries, I appreciate the input.

Comment: Nice – but a bit unexpected. Looks as if `+` was a special syntax at first glance, only then noticing what's actually going on. So in the end I'd rather prefer explicit return type (`using func = void(); func* select();`) – I consider that superior especially as one doesn't have to look into the code to determine return type.